# Regex, only match with strings that contain one occurence of certain characters

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
^[-]?([+]?[\d]+[-+*/]?)+$
```

My objective is to match strings that contain arithmetic expressions and integers. Which it is successful in, except one case. When it comes to equals signs. I only want this expression to match strings that contain at most one equals sign. Which would mean that it would match

> 7=7

but not

> 7=7=7

since the second string has two occurrences of the equals sign.

I tried using curly braces {} and I think I need something like

```
={0,1}
```

which would match with strings that have exactly one or no occurrencces of "=". But I do unfortunately not know how to incorporate it in my regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want to match arithmetic expressions and integers I changed your code to find everything if it has numbers, operators or a equal sign: `^[-+*\/\d=]+$`. I needed to escape the character `/` -> `\/`

To match only one equal sign I addes a negative lookahead: `(?!.*=.*=)`. If it finds whats insinde the brackets, the whole regex wont match. For example if you have a word mytext :  `(?!mytext)` the whole regex won't match. `.*` means it finds everything (`.` stands for every character and the `*` say's it can be there 0 to unlimited times).

So this is the solution:

```
^(?!.*=.*=)[-+*\/\d=]+$
```

See live example here:
https://regex101.com/r/zhSEmf/1/

Also your code didn't worked for -4*-4.

Edit: Since you don't want your code to start with / or * I added id in the negative lookahead: `^(?!.*=.*=|[\/*].*)[-+*\/\d=]+$`

Comment: I do not want to indicate negativity or positivity of numbers  in the middle of the expression. So `7/+6 ` is not ok whereas `+7/6`is ok

Comment: Ok, but you can still use (?!.*=.*=) at the beginning of your regex to get only solutions with one equal sign.

Comment: Also I do not know how complex your operations will be or how its constructed. If you want a more precise solution you will need to add more informations in your question.

Comment: This matches strings with no occurrences of `=`. So `55` is a match. Also matched is `5=` or `=5`. Probably, this is not a desired match.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to match strings with only one equals sign then you want to not match strings with no equals and also not match strings with more than one equals. A regex like so:

```
^(?!.*=.*=)(?![^=]*$)[-+*\/\d=]+$
```

Unfortunately, this will match strings like `9=`. Probably not desired.

I suspect then that you want to both match strings of form a=b and strings of form a, where a and b are arithmetic expressions. This even handles negative numbers:

```
^-?\d+([-+*\/]-?\d+)*(=-?\d+([-+*\/]-?\d+)*)?$
```

See live example here: https://regex101.com/r/9vONUT/1